# Не работает стрелочная функция

Tags: javascript, функции, синтаксис

При записи стрелочной функции с круглыми скобками для аргументов и фигурными для тела функции код перестает работать (хотя согласно синтаксису таких функций все должно быть норм). Если убрать скобки, все в порядке (работающий код закомментирован). Почему это происходит?

```js
const mainForm = document.forms.main;
const mainFormSelect = mainForm.nameSelect;

let arraySelected = Array.from(mainFormSelect.options)
       .filter((option) => {option.selected})
        .map((option) => {option.value})
    // .filter(option => option.selected)
    // .map(option => option.value);

console.log(arraySelected);
```

```html
<form action="#" name="main">
  <select multiple class="" name="nameSelect">
    <option value="1" selected>100</option>
    <option value="7">800</option>
    <option value="2" selected>550</option>
  </select>
</form>
```